# how to set the field as read only in the Infopath 2010 form based on user logged in?

Tags: infopath

I have designed an Infopath 2010 Form and set a formatting rule which will disable the field based on the user logged in.

It works fine for the new form.

However the field become enabled if a user opens an existing form.

setup:
have created a empty field to store the logged in username and set the rule based on the value of the field.

Issue is that value is assigned to the field when the form is submitted and it is not refreshing whenever the form is loaded.

Is there a way to refresh the field value whenever the form is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your rules on the form load event of the form. So that you can put any actions in your rules in the form load.

Comment: How to create rules on the form load event of the form?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jw7fnPHjkEg

Comment: Here are some articles relate to: [link1](https://tfs.qssolutions.nl/tfs/Products/Work%20Sprints/_workitems) [link2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/anneste/archive/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)